# Does HI-6 form a covalent adduct with acetylcholinesterase?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, drugs, proteins, enzymes

According to sources provided below, the oxime HI-6, or Asoxime Dichloride, as it is also called, besides being a reactivator of acetylcholinesterase that has been inhibited by organophosphorus compounds, can act as an AChE inhibitor itself.In the process of inhibiting AChE, does HI-6 form a covalent adduct with the enzyme (Similarly to how TMTFA forms an adduct) or is the inhibition due to HI-6 simply occupying the active site without covalently binding with the enzyme?

**References:**

1. Soukup O, Pohanka M, Tobin G, et al. The effect of HI-6 on
   cholinesterases and on the cholinergic system of the rat bladder.
   Neuro Endocrinol Lett. **2008**;29(5):759-762.
2. Pohanka, M. (**2012**). Alpha7 Nicotinic Acetylcholine Receptor Is a
   Target in Pharmacology and Toxicology. International Journal of
   Molecular Sciences, 13(2), 2219–2238. doi:10.3390/ijms13022219
3. Pohanka, M. (**2013**). HI-6 modulates immunization efficacy in a BALB/c
   mouse model. Environmental Toxicology and Pharmacology, 36(3),
   801–806. doi:10.1016/j.etap.2013.07.012